# How to track the memory leak in Java?

Tags: java, debugging, memory-leaks

I have a code which will down in  several hours, the log shows

```
java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: GC overhead limit exceeded
        at java.io.FileDescriptor.<init>(FileDescriptor.java:62)
        at sun.nio.ch.ServerSocketChannelImpl.accept(ServerSocketChannelImpl.java:217)
        at org.jboss.netty.channel.socket.nio.NioServerSocketPipelineSink$Boss.run(NioServerSocketPipelineSink.java:235)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1110)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:603)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722)
```

How to track the issue like this? Is there any tool can help?
The stack not point me any line in the code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Heap dumps are the ones need to be analyzed to find out root causes for memory leaks.

There are tools like [jhat](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/tools/share/jhat.html) and jprofiler etc., which will be used to analyze heap dumps.

Answer (score 2):

There are a lot of tools for cpu and memory usage monitoring of Java applications. For example, in JDK 1.6 you can find `jvisualvm` profiling tool. Also there is Sun Profiling Studio which include `collect` command that can be used with `-j` option (see docs for details).

**P.S.** `collect` command provide much fun - it can display assemly code that was actually executed.

Answer (score 0):

You have many options to solve your trouble. Here are free monitoring tools, see this

- [JRat](http://jrat.sourceforge.net/)
- [Cougaar](http://profiler.cougaar.org/)
- [Java Application Monitor (JAMon)](http://www.jamonapi.com)
- [InfraRED](http://infrared.sourceforge.net/versions/latest/)
- jconsole (already consisted in JVM)
- jvisualvm (already consisted in JVM version 1.6 x)